# Get the returned list of uploaded files in the order they were uploaded using the Filestack API?

Tags: javascript, api, file-upload

When using V2 pickMultiple or pickAndStore in multiple mode, is there a way to get the returned list of uploaded files in the order they were uploaded?

Comment: Can you post the code you have now?